# Алгоритм поиска максимальной суммы непрерывной подпоследовательности

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Дана последовательность (массив) целых чисел. Числа могут быть как отрицательные так и положительные. Предложите самый быстрый алгоритм поиска наибольшей суммы непрерывной последовательности.

Comment: Круто, хорошая задачка :)

Comment: Я тоже нагуглил, даже отвечать не стал =)

Comment: Знаю только самый простой:(:(:(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
array = list( map( int, raw_input().split() ) )
max_sum = [ 0, ]
for x in array:
    tmp = max_sum[ -1 ] + x
    if tmp < 0:
        tmp = 0
    max_sum.append( tmp )
print max( max_sum )
```

http://ideone.com/y3Nwd

Соблюдается условие, что последовательность может быть пуста. Работает за O(n).

Comment: Зачем делать `list()` на `array`? Лишняя память на список, вроде бы, дело вполне обошлось бы генератором.

Comment: Может быть я ошибаюсь, но при всех отрицательных элементах массива выдаст 0, при этом должно быть максимальное из отрицательных?

Comment: @anatoliy_v "Соблюдается условие, что последовательность может быть пуста."

Comment: [не обязательно список составлять, если только сумму нужно найти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654695/23044)

Answer (score 17):

Решение - [**Алгоритм Кадане**](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/maximum_average_segment), кому интересно посмотрите ) думаю лучше уже не придумать...

Answer (score 7):

Книга «Жемчужины программирования» Джона Бентли (1984) подробно разбирает эту задачу (показаны `O(n**3)`, `O(n**2)`, `O(n * log n)` и наконец `O(n)` алгоритм). Реализация классического [алгоритма Кадане](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) на Питоне:

```py
def maxsum(iterable):
    maxsofar = maxendinghere = 0
    for x in iterable:
        maxendinghere = max(maxendinghere + x, 0)
        maxsofar = max(maxsofar, maxendinghere)
    return maxsofar
```

Это `O(n)` (линейный однопроходной) алгоритм с `O(1)` (постоянной) памятью: используются только две переменные (для текущей и наибольшей суммы). Пример:

```
>>> maxsum([1, 2, -5, 3, 2, -1, 5, -10, 3, 2])
9
```

То же самое на С++:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

template<class InputIterator>
intmax_t maxsum(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
  intmax_t maxsofar = 0, maxendinghere = 0;
  for ( ; first != last; ++first) {
    maxendinghere = std::max(maxendinghere + *first, (intmax_t)0);
    maxsofar = std::max(maxsofar, maxendinghere);
  }
  return maxsofar;
}
```

Пример:

```bsh
$ g++ -std=c++11     maxsum.cc   -o maxsum
$ ./maxsum <<<'1 2 -5 3 2 -1 5 -10 3 2'
9
```

где `main()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  std::istream_iterator<int> numbers(std::cin), eof;
  std::cout << maxsum(numbers, eof) << std::endl;
}
```

Тот же код работает и для явного массива:

```cpp
int main()
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, -5, 3, 2, -1, 5, -10, 3, 2};
  std::cout << maxsum(std::begin(a), std::end(a)) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение за O(n)

Чтобы получить максимальную сумму подпоследовательности, заканчивающейся на i-ом элементе(обозначим это значение за f(i)), нужно исключить из последовательности с 1-го по i-ый элемент префикс с минимальной суммой. Остается только найти максимум по всем f(i).

Реализация на Haskell

```
main = fmap (print . maxsum . map read . words) getLine

maxsum xs = let sums = scanl (+) 0 xs
                        in maximum $ zipWith (-) sums $ scanl1 min sums
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой алгоритм. Переменная `maX` хранит максимальную последовательность, а переменная `maXX` хранить непрерывную последовательность на данном шаге, и если она больше максимальной, то переменная `maX` обновляется. Работает за O(n). Ниже код на C ++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int massiv[1000];
int maXX,maX;


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cin>>massiv[i];
    }

    maXX=massiv[1];
    maX=massiv[1];
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        maXX=max(maXX+massiv[i],massiv[i]);
        if (maXX>maX)
            maX=maXX;

    }
    cout<<maX;

        return(0);

}
```

Comment: Неужели неверно?!

Answer (score 1):

Так это массив или последовательность? В последовательности есть зависимость членов. Тогда надо просто узнать, убывающая она или возрастающая. Если она убывает, идем с начала до первого нуля или отрицательного. если возрастает, то до идем с конца. Как-то так

```
if (mass[0] > mass[1]) {
    float sum = mass[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < count(mass); i++)
        if (mass[i] > 0)
            sum += mass[i];
} else {
    float sum = mass[count(mass) - 1];
    for (int i = count(mass) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (mass[i] > 0)
            sum += mass[i];
}
```

Comment: Последовательность — это набор элементов некоторого множества.

Answer (score 1):

Задача, на самом деле, не совсем логична. Ведь, давайте представим такой массив:

```
 int a[16] = {-6,2,5,1,0,3,4,5,8,8,10,9,11,23,14,25};
```

Ведь его можно разделить всего на две части: первые два числа и все остальное. При чем все остальное - есть непрерывная последовательность, сумма элементов которой больше суммы первой подгруппы. Так можно делать с каждым массивом: тупо бить его на две или три части последовательно. Подумайте сами. Задача либо требует уточнений( например, максимальное количество элементов в последовательности ), либо не верна.

---

**К примеру, я придумал такой алгоритм( *Работа алгоритма производится за линейное время. Это придает алгоритму краткость и понятность.* ):**

(Алгоритм основан на том, что каждое отрицательное значение дает минус в сумме подгруппы )

```
int sums[16] = {0};
int a[16] = {-6,1,-2,0,1,1,-17,1,0,1,-100,1,1,-1,-1,1};
int n = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<16;i++)
{
    if(a[i]>=0)
    for(int j=n;j<=i;j++) sums[j]+=a[i];
    else n=i;
}
int max = 0; int ind = 0;
for(int j=0;j<16;j++)
{
    cout<<sums[j]<<endl;
    if(sums[j]>max) {max = sums[j]; ind=j;} 
}

cout<<"The longest subarray in array begins in "<<ind+1<<" position! Sum  =  "<<max<<endl;
```

Comment: последовательность не обязательно должна быть возрастающая или убывающая. у нее просто должна быть сумма элементов наибольшая. например, `3, -2, 4` даст ответ `5`.

Comment: Ну, так, а я про что? Я говорю, что можно тупо бить последовательность на 2-3 части и искать из кусков наиболее больший по сумме элементов.

Comment: попробуйте такой ввод:

    int a[16] = {-6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-100,1,1,1,-1,1};

Comment: Спасибо, Юра Иванов. Я Написал новый алгоритм. Можете проверить...

---
Работает =)

Comment: см. мой первый комментарий. 3, -2, 4. результат должен быть 5, у вас будет 4.

Answer (score 1):

Пробегаемся от начала массива и на i-ом шаге храним сумму массива с 0 по i-ый элемент, а также минимальную сумму к этому шагу, которую мы когда-либо вычисляли до этого и на каждом шаге релаксируем ответ на основе этих двух чисел.

```
int s=0,mins=0,ans=0;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
  s+=a[i];
  mins=min(mins,s);
  ans=max(ans,s-mins);
}
//ans - ответ
```

Сложность O(n)

Answer (score 1):

```
def hashcode(c):
if len(c) == 1: return c[0]
try:
    while c[0] <= 0: # Удаляем отрицательные числа с краев
        c.pop(0)
except IndexError: # Все числа в списке отрицательны или пустой список
    return 0 
while c[-1] <= 0:
    c.pop() 
summa = 0
cnew = []
for i in c:
    if i * summa >= 0:
        summa += i
    else:
        cnew.append(summa)
        summa = i
cnew.append(summa) # Делаем список из сумм последовательностей чисел одного знака
num = cnew.index(max(cnew))
cnew2 = []
for i in range(0, num, 2):
    cnew2.append(cnew[i] + cnew[i+1]) # Складываем соседние числа
cnew2.append(cnew[num]) # максимальный элемент оставляем без изменения
for i in range(num + 1, len(cnew), 2):
    cnew2.append(cnew[i] + cnew[i+1])
return hashcode(cnew2) # Рекурсивно повторяем
```

import random
a = [random.randint(-10, 10) for i in range(100000)]
print(hashcode(a))

Comment: Эх, отступы слетели... (((

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой алгоритм у меня придумался, конечно, я не уверен, что он самый быстрый, но, по крайней мере, немедленный. Писал на Delphi. Ещё такой вопрос: если элементы равны, то это считается последовательностью равных элементов или как? У меня так: если они изначально равны, то перехожу к следующему элементу, а если равные элементы попадутся в самой последовательности (неважно какой возрастающей или убывающей), то к такому типу последовательности они и относятся. Равные идущие подряд элементы, я бы всё-таки обрабатывал как последовательность равных элементов, но по аналогии это сделать несложно.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

Const
  N0 = 100;

Type
  Massif=Array[0..N0-1] Of Integer;

Var
  Mas: Massif;
  i, j, u, v, n: Byte;
  Sum, MaxSum: LongInt;

Function Rus(Str: String): String;
Var
  i: Integer;

Begin
  For i:=1 To Length(Str) Do
    Case Str[i] Of
      'А'..'п' : Str[i] := Chr(Ord(Str[i]) - 64);
      'р'..'я' : Str[i] := Chr(Ord(Str[i]) - 16);
    End;

  Rus:=Str;
End;

begin

  Repeat
    Write(Rus('Введи размер (1 < N <= 100): N = '));
    Readln(N);
  Until ((N > 1) And (N < 101)); // проверяю пользователя

  WriteLn(Rus('Вводи массив:'));

  For i:=0 To N-1 Do // ввожу массив
    Begin
      Write('Mas[', i+1, '] = ');
      ReadLn(Mas[i]);
    End;

  i:=0;
  MaxSum:=Low(LongInt); // максимальная сумма
  While (i < N) Do
    Begin
      j:=i;
      Sum:=0;
      If (Mas[j] < Mas[j+1]) Then // возрастающая последовательность
        While (j < N) Do
          Begin
            Sum:=Sum + Mas[j];
            If (Mas[j] > Mas[j+1]) Then Break; // если последовательность нарушена, выход
            Inc(j);
          End
      Else If (Mas[j] > Mas[j+1]) Then  // убывающая последовательность
        While (j < N) Do
          Begin
            Sum:=Sum + Mas[j];
            If (Mas[j] < Mas[j+1]) Then Break;
            Inc(j);
          End
      Else  // оба соседних элемента равны
      // (это событие лучше обрабатывать как последовательность равных элементов)
        Begin
          Inc(i);
          Continue;
        End;

      If (Sum > MaxSum) Then // сравниваю сумму с максимальной
        Begin
          MaxSum:=Sum;
          u:=i; // начало последовательности
          v:=j; // конец последовательности
        End;
      i:=j+1; // пересчитываю индекс, нарушившего последовательность, элемента
    End;

  WriteLn;
  WriteLn(Rus('Наибольшая сумма = '), MaxSum); // вывожу результат
  WriteLn(Rus('Начало = '), u+1);
  WriteLn(Rus('Конец = '), v+1);
  WriteLn;

  WriteLn(Rus('Дави на ЭНТЕР!'));
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: `Vvedi razmer(1 < N <= 100) facepalm.jpg`

Comment: @Asen2, я не понимаю в чём смысл этого комментария, но удалять его не стал.

Comment: Он о кириллице, точнее, об её отсутствии. Как-никак, в 21 веке живем.

Comment: Для слишком уж принципиальных пользователей, код переписал для вывода кириллицы. Когда писал, то эту неприоритетную задачу перед собой не ставил: нужен алгоритм, а не способ вывода кириллицы на консоль!

Answer (score -1):

Не помню я уже, как точно надо ее решать, но задача из области динамического программирования. По идее, должен быть построен массив с суммами для каждой возможной последовательности, из него выбрана максимальная сумма, а потом обратно развертывается последовательность этой суммы. У Кормена есть глава по ДП.

Answer (score -1):

Допустим у нас массив а[n];

Тогда вводим номер элемента с которого начнем считать суму и которым закончим.

```
int first, final, sumResult;    
first = Console.ReadLine();    
final = Console.ReadLine();    
try    
{    
     for (int i=first, i<=final; i++)    
     {        
         sumResult+=a[i];        
     }     
}
catch(Exeption e)    
{    
     Console.ReadLine("Введен несуществующий элемент массива");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

максимальная сумма последовательности будет тогда и только тогда, когда сложены только положительные числа. Исходя из этого пишем программу.
мне лень очень писать эту программу потому что она лёгкая. объсню вкратце.
сначало заполняем массив числами через цикл for. потом опять с помощью цикла for складываем только положительные числа. что то типо эого.

```
int n; // n это количество чисел в массиве.
int max_sum = 0; // это максимальная сумма
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        if (chisla[i] > 0)
        {max_sum +=chisla[i];
        }
    }
далее просто выводим
```

нужную нам переменную через cout