# Задача на последовательности в массиве (ЕГЭ)

Tags: c

Дан целочисленный массив из 30 элементов. Опишите алгоритм, который находит и выводит сумму наибольшей по длине возрастающей последовательности подряд идущих элементов. Если таких последовательностей несколько, можно вывести любую из них.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
int dig[10];
int i,sum,dlina,dlinamax,maxsum;

for (i = 0 ; i <= 4 ;i++){
   scanf("%d",&dig[i]);
}

for ( i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++){
   dlina = 1;
   sum = dig[i];
   if (dig[i] < dig[i + 1]){
      sum += dig[i + 1];
      dlina++;
   }
   if (dlina > dlinamax){
      dlinamax = dlina;
      maxsum = sum;
   }
}
printf("Сумма самой длинной возрастающей последовательности: %d\n",maxsum);
}
```

Исправил:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
int dig[10];
int i,sum,dlina,dlinamax,maxsum;

for (i = 0 ; i <= 9 ;i++){
   scanf("%d",&dig[i]);
}
maxsum = 0;
dlinamax = 0;
for ( i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++){
   dlina = 1;
   sum = dig[i];
   if (dig[i] > dig[i - 1]){
      sum += dig[i];
      dlina++;
   }
   if (dlina > dlinamax){
      dlinamax = dlina;
      maxsum = sum;
   }
}
printf("Сумма самой длинной возрастающей последовательности: %d\n",maxsum);
}
```

теперь постоянно пишет 4

Comment: У вас выход за границы массива в цикле, да и читаете 5 элементов, а пробегаете 10. Остальные 5 - это то, что лежало в памяти до этого (мусор)

Comment: Не могу понять,как исправить.

Comment: Очень просто: не выходите за границу массива в цикле, и читайте не 5, а 10 элементов. Какой из пунктов вызывает вопросы?

Comment: А где я вышел за границы массива?

Comment: При `i == 9` вы обращаетесь к `dig[i + 1]`.

Comment: for ( i = 0 ; i <= 8 ; i++)
всё-равно не работает

Comment: dlinamax еще не инициализирована, как собственно и maxsum

Comment: Теперь постоянно 3 выводит,беда

Comment: Во-первых, вы читаете всего 5 цифр, а не 10. Во-вторых, у вас совершенно неправильный алгоритм. Эта задача решается средствами динамического программирования. Почитайте [статью][1], в которой это расписано.

  [1]: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/longest_increasing_subseq_log

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Алгоритм поиска максимальной суммы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129360/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
  int dig[10];
  int i,sum,dlina,dlinamax,maxsum;

  for (i = 0 ; i <= 9 ;i++){
    scanf("%d",&dig[i]);
  }
  maxsum = dig[0];
  dlinamax = 0;
  dlina = 1;
  for ( i = 1 ; i <= 9 ; i++){
    if (dig[i] <= dig[i-1]){
      if (dlina > dlinamax) {
        dlinamax = dlina;
        maxsum = sum;
      }
      sum = dig[i];
      dlina = 1;
    } else {
      sum += dig[i];
      dlina++;
    }
  }
  printf("Сумма самой длинной возрастающей последовательности: %d\n",maxsum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое что ты делаешь только для первых 5ти элементов 
т.е. вводишь только первые 5 чисел

```
 for (i = 0 ; i <= 4 ;i++){
       scanf("%d",&dig[i]);
    }
```

Но далее

```
for ( i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++){
```

ты бежишь до 10го элемента, а 6-7-8-9-10 нет, ты же их не вводил ни где.

Если я правильно понимаю синтаксис С, то ошибка во втором цикле!

Ну и хорошо бы прилагать ошибки, которые возникают при работе программы!

//upd

первый же

```
if (dig[i] > dig[i - 1]){
```

не удостаивается чести на выполнение, т.к. у тебя массив от 0-9, а ты просишь его узнать про -1 элемент массива - что неправильно!

и во вторых толстых.

```
for ( i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++){
   dlina = 1;
   sum = dig[i];
   if (dig[i] > dig[i - 1]){
      sum += dig[i];
      dlina++;
   }
   if (dlina > dlinamax){
      dlinamax = dlina;
      maxsum = sum;
   }
}
```

Что вообще за логика работы сего кода?
Он делает чушь, возьми листок бумаги и рукой все действия напиши. Вчитался в код и понял, что не хочу дальше думать. Тут нужно менять логику работы программы, криво написана. А то что выводит 4ку вполне закономерно. (возьми ручку и посчитай)