# Задача на последовательность сумма подряд идущих

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Всем привет есть такая задача, она даёт у меня тайм лимит. Ограничение задачи 2 секунды.

Вот задача:

> Со входного устройства поступает последовательность целых чисел. Длина последовательности неизвестна. Требуется найти максимальную сумму подряд идущих элементов после­довательности. Элементы последовательности читать до конца ввода.
>
> Формат входных данных
>
> Последовательность целых чисел, разделенных одним или несколькими пробелами или переводом строки.
>
> Формат выходных данных
>
> В одной строке искомая максимальная сумма.
>
> Пример входных данных
>
> 1 2 -5 3 2 -1 5 -10 3 2
>
> Пример выходных данных
>
> 9

А вот мой код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<int>ciss;
  int cis,sum=0,ii=0,summax=0;
  while(cin>>cis)
    ciss.push_back(cis);
  for(int i=0;i<ciss.size();i++)
  {
    sum=0;
    for(int j=i;j<ciss.size();j++)
    {
      sum+=ciss[j];
      if(sum>summax)
        summax=sum;
    }
  }
  cout<<summax<<endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

как избежать тайм лимита в этой задаче ?

Comment: Вероятно, надо уйти от тупого перебора и придумать что-нибудь более осмысленное...

Comment: @Akina да ладно ))

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129360/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B

Comment: @Akina сразу бы как дубликат уже отмечали.

Comment: Далеко вам еще до "туриста". Ответ уже привели выше, но задача из области динамического программирования, поэтому  рекомендую вывести реккурентную формулу для глубокого понимания проблемы.

Comment: Оно-то вроде и дубль... но ответ там на Питоне.

Comment: @Harry а ещё там ответы на C++ и Haskell.

Comment: @jfs С излишним сохранением в массив?

Comment: @Harry: 1- причём здесь тогда Питон? 2- никто не заставляет вас в массив сохранять (достаточно только текущую и наибольшую суммы хранить). Для ясности я добавил [явные однопроходные реализации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654695/23044) 3- ваш код очень похож на реализацию данную по ссылке в одном из ответов в вопросе-дубликате.

Comment: @jfs Жаль, что не могу принятый ответ удалить, чтоб дискуссию не разводить... Достали уже сплошные "это не делай, так нельзя, это плохо" - нет, не от вас, вы просто та последняя капля... Найти бы другой такой сайт, где можно так здорово отдыхать от основной работы - уже свалил бы туда :(

Comment: @Harry не надо ни куда сваливать .Такие специалисты как вы нужны этому сайту !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде бы так `O(n)` дает - накапливаем частичные суммы и ищем максимальную разность наибольшего справа с наименьшим слева:

```
int main()
{
    int n, sum = 0, min = 0, max = 0;
    while(cin >> n)
    {
        sum += n;
        if (sum < min) min = sum;
        else if (sum - min > max) max = sum - min;
    }
    cout << max << endl;
}
```